# VBA Running a Variable Loop during a Worksheet Change Event

Tags: vba, loops, events, target, worksheet

Having trouble getting a variable loop working.

The spreadsheet works by pasting new data into the next blank row in column A to H, and has a variable number of rows each time.

The change event happens when the target row in column A is <> 0 and information is extrapolated from the pasted data and shown in columns J to N. But this code only works on the top line of new data. I believe it requires a loop but I am unsure how to make this work?

I've tried to find a good example online but I am struggling and failing with each attempt. Massive thanks to anyone who can help me or point me in the right direction!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
On Error GoTo enditall
If Target.Cells.Column = 1 Then

    n = Target.row
    arange = Range("A" & n)
    brange = Range("B" & n)
    crange = Range("C" & n)
    drange = Range("D" & n)
    erange = Range("E" & n)
    frange = Range("F" & n)
    grange = Range("G" & n)
    hrange = Range("H" & n)

    Dim myRange As Excel.Range
    Dim myCell As Excel.Range
    Set myRange = Target

Application.EnableEvents = False

For Each myCell In myRange.Cells
If Excel.Range("A" & n).Value <> "" Then
    Excel.Range("J" & n) = DateValue(Left(hrange, 10))
    Excel.Range("k" & n) = Left(brange, 3)
    Excel.Range("L" & n) = Mid(brange, 5, 2)
    Excel.Range("M" & n) = Left(drange, 1)
    If Excel.Range("M" & n) = "B" Then Excel.Range("N" & n) = erange
    If Excel.Range("M" & n) = "S" Then Excel.Range("N" & n) = erange * -1
End If
Next

End If
```

enditall:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    Dim rw As Range

    If Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'On Error GoTo enditall

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each rw In Target.Rows

        If rw.Cells(1, "A").Value <> "" Then
            rw.Cells(1, "J") = DateValue(Left(rw.Cells(1, "H"), 10))
            rw.Cells(1, "k") = Left(rw.Cells(1, "B"), 3)
            rw.Cells(1, "L") = Mid(rw.Cells(1, "B"), 5, 2)
            rw.Cells(1, "M") = Left(rw.Cells(1, "D"), 1)
            If rw.Cells(1, "M") = "B" Then rw.Cells(1, "N") = rw.Cells(1, "E")
            If rw.Cells(1, "M") = "S" Then rw.Cells(1, "N") = rw.Cells(1, "E") * -1
        End If

    Next rw

enditall:

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```